# Recursion - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python

```
def main():
    string = raw_input("string:")
    pattern = raw_input("pattern:")
    end = len(string)
    recursiveinsertPattern(string,pattern)

def recursiveinsertPattern(string, pattern):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return ""
    else:
        print string[0]+pattern+recursiveinsertPattern(string[1:],pattern),
```

So I need this to output

```
*h*e*l*l*o*
```

if the string input is `hello` and the pattern input is `*`. But I'm getting this error when trying to add the last run through:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: whats the use of pattern here???

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't show them but there are asterisks between each letter in hello

Comment: because u are concaneting the pattern

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your function `recursiveinsertPattern` only return "" when `len(string) == 1`, and `None` otherwise.

I would modify this function so that it looks like this:

```
def recursiveinsertPattern(string, pattern):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return ""
    else:
        return string[0]+pattern+recursiveinsertPattern(string[1:],pattern)
```

And `print` result of this function in `main()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the result of `recursiveinsertPattern`, you want to return it. The error is because you don't return a value for `recursiveinsertPattern`. You want:

```
def main():
    string = raw_input("string:")
    pattern = raw_input("pattern:")
    end = len(string)
    print recursiveinsertPattern(string,pattern)

def recursiveinsertPattern(string, pattern):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return ""
    else:
        return string[0]+pattern+recursiveinsertPattern(string[1:],pattern),
```

Answer (score 0):

Also change your condition.. instead of `1` change it to `0` so that the last character will be included.. just copy and paste this snippet

```
def recursiveinsertPattern(string, pattern):
if len(string) == 0:
    return ""
else:
    return string[0]+pattern+recursiveinsertPattern(string[1:],pattern)
```